# Upload draft APK without interfering with published APK?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a published app. The app uses Google's license check, so in order to test new versions of the app (using the test accounts) the `APK` must be uploaded in the Developer Console:

*The account owner (but not the other test accounts) will also get this response for applications that have not been uploaded to Google Play yet.*

I've done this several times. It's a no-brainer. Well, until now.

After uploading my new `APK` as 'draft production', it gives me this warning message:

*Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.*

This makes me nervous as **I do NOT want to publish** this new version.

[image]

Previously, I simply marked my latest `APK` as `Inactivated` and I was all set. How can this be done in the new Developer Console?

**Q: How do I upload a new unpublished `APK` to be testable with Google's license check?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uploading the `APK` and clicking `Save draft` is enough to get the license check working. The new `APK` will not be published until you explicitly publish it. The error message is simply there to pinpoint a problem which would arise if you choose to publish the app.